# PayPal Digital Goods: How to get item number after purchase made?

Tags: php, paypal

I got a simple Digital Goods Checkout to work in Sandbox mode. I have a "Pay with PayPal" button that I can click which pops up an window for logging into PayPal. After that it redirects me to my `purchasemade.php` script, and from there I can successfully download a file.

My problem is that on my website I'm going to sell many products, so I need to know which product they want to download when they finish the purchase. Each product has a unique ID, so I thought I'd pass that ID as the item number in the HTML form as a hidden field named "item_number". However, I don't know how to read that value once I reach the `purchasemade.php`.

How do I read values passed in POST in the original form? Otherwise, what's the best way of identifying a product? I'm using PHP as my scripting language for this project.

Comment: Do you put the ID of your product in a session (or a basket)? If so, when Paypal indicates that the user paid successfully, use the contents of the session to determine what the user may download before clearing the session.

Comment: Oddly enough, I tried sessions and they don't work. For some reason, once I return to my website from PayPal, the SESSION is reset

Comment: That will be a bug on your side. A (payment) site on a different site has no ability to clear sessions on your own domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to stick with [Payments Standard](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview) I would recommend using [IPN](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/ipnguide.pdf) to deliver your digital goods.  You could use [PDT](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/pdt-techview-outside) (which is very similar to IPN) to send order data back to the page the user gets redirected to, however, there is no guarantee they will make here even with Auto-Return enabled in your PayPal account.

Alternatively, you could use the [Express Checkout API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec) instead of Payments Standard.  This method guarantees the user will make it back to your site prior to completing payment.  This will allow you to utilize session variables so you can present the download to the user on the thank you/receipt page.

Still, though, I think IPN would be your best bet regardless of which way you go.  You can use it to auto-deliver the digital goods, send out general email notifications, update your database, hit third party web services, etc. all in real-time.